# hook function failed using push/retn method

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, x86, hook

I try to hook a function by push/retn method,the program compile  and runs successfully. it should pop up a "hook success" dialog,however it pop up a "not hook" diaglog. what's wrong with it ?

program run on VS 2017 ,win 10

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.text,ERW") 

//the original function 
void func() {
    MessageBox(0, L"not hook", L"info", MB_OK);
}
void hookproc() {
    MessageBox(0, L"hook success",L"info", MB_OK);
}
void hook_code() {
    BYTE *lpFunc1 = (BYTE*)func;
    lpFunc1[0] = 0x68;//machine code of push
    *(ULONG_PTR *)&lpFunc1[1] = (ULONG_PTR)hookproc;//hook function
    lpFunc1[5] = 0xC3;//machine code of retn
}
int main()
{
    hook_code();
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a proper method to hook functions.

Comment: Did you build this as a release build rather than a debug build? I will assume that was an x86 target and not an x64 target.

Comment: thank you very much ! when I change release to debug and use x86 to build,it works. when I use debug x64 to build,the program crash .could you tell me the reason? i am a beginner to learn hook @Michael Petch

Comment: Release builds have optimizations on and the function `func1` is likely being inlined and the function removed. The code in `func1` was inlined into the `main` function. If you look at the disassembly output you'd likely find that to to be the case. As for 64-bit (x64) code the calling convention is different and there is a required 32 **byte** [shadow space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019) (home space) to be allocated on the stack just prior to making a call.

Comment: I got it ! thank you for your answer sincerely ！@Michael Petch

Comment: @MichaelPetch Not to mention that opcode `0x68` is a 32-bit push, which doesn't work out so great on a 64-bit system.